# How to solve {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} error?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

So I deployed an API (aws api gateway) and when I got the invoke url and filled in the parameters, I get the following error:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

I looked at cloud watch and the lambda function was called, but the parameters I fed it were all empty. And I have no idea whats going on.

Here is my invoke url:

```
https://mupb23gx76.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/userAPI/adduser
```

Here is the invoke url with all the parameters:

```
https://mupb23gx76.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/userAPI/adduser?username=karan&firstName=karan&lastName=chitnis&email=gmail&profileImageURL=whatever&phoneNumber=555&birthdate=0109
```

Here is a screen shot of my api structure:

[image]
And here is the input model i made for the method request.

```
{
    "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "email":{"type":"string"},
        "birthdate":{"type":"string"},
        "firstName":{"type":"string"},
        "lastName":{"type":"string"},
        "userName":{"type":"string"},
        "phoneNumber":{"type":"string"},
        "profileImageURL":{"type":"string"}
    },
    "title":"InputaddUser"
}
```

I DID NOT PUT QUERY STRING PARAMETERS in my method request, I just put added this model. Because I plan on deploying this to android. But I wanted to make sure it worked on invoke url first.

**UPDATE**

Here is my cloudwatch when i put the url into to Postman. [image]

And here is my inputbody:

```
{
  "email": "qgseg@gmail.com",
  "birthdate": "1/1/1990",
  "firstName": "Qazar",
  "lastName": "Fbaooqui",
  "username": "Caster",
  "phoneNumber": "some #",
  "profileImageURL":"something"
}
```

Comment: I've encountered this error before when API Gateway didn't have permission to execute the function properly, though it sounds like from your description that isn't the case. Are you able to post the Cloudwatch lambda invocation logs?

Comment: @rumdrums  so when i post the url into Postman and giving the input body, the lambda function DOES get contacted. But all my strings are empty. Ill post what i get on cloud watch right now

Comment: @rumdrums just updated!

Answer (score 2):

You've configured this method as a `POST`. When I request the resource with the correct verb it seems to work:

```
> curl -XPOST https://mupb23gx76.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/userAPI/adduser?username=karan&firstName=karan&lastName=chitnis&email=gmail&profileImageURL=whatever&phoneNumber=555&birthdate=0109

{
   "output" : "success"
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "correct verb"? im trying it on my browser and Postman its a no go for me? can you please explain?

Comment: @TheQ HTTP Methods (GET, POST, PUT) are often called verbs. Make sure that you set this correctly in Postman.